Can I use a forward transformer in a flyback converter circuit?
I'm working on a power supply project and was wondering if it's possible to use a transformer designed for a forward converter in a flyback converter circuit.
I understand that these two topologies have different operating principles, but I wanted to know if it's feasible with some modifications or if it would cause significant issues.
Circuit parameters:

Input: 30 V
Output: ±150 V ±60 mA
Frequency: 300 kHz


I decided to use a forward transformer because they are cheaper, smaller and have lower DCR and leakage inductance. I did simulations with WE 750315228 transformer and it seems to work fine. But today I got confused when I was reading TI's Under the Hood of Flyback SMPS Designs article because the author says that there are major differences between flyback transformers and other transformer types. I know that the parameters like inductance, turns ratio and leakage are different but is there a reason that prevents me from using a forward/push-pull transformer in a flyback circuit?
Any insights or recommendations from those who have tried this or have experience with these transformers would be appreciated.

You can't, at least for most practical purposes, because a forward converter has a transformer without an air gap, and the energy storage is taken care of in an inductor just after the transformer, usually. A forward converter therefore has a transformer without an air gap, and an additional inductor. In a flyback converter, the transformer also stores the energy, and therefore has an air gap.
It helps to think of a flyback transformer this way: It is an inductor (with an air gap in the core, so it's the device that stores the energy), and the inductor has two windings. One winding is connected to the input (primary) and the other winding is connected to the output (secondary). Using two windings, you end up with a flyback converter (isolated output), but basically, it is just a step-up converter with two circuiuts.

Thanks for your help. So is it because the transformer will saturate at high currents? I just realized that there's a parameter called Voltage-µSecond in the transformers datasheets. It's 8.5 Vus for 750315228. For my circuit primary voltage is 30 V and on-time is 2.3 uS which makes 70 Vus. Is that the reason why I can't use this transformer. My last question is if I had very low primary and secondary voltages and higher switching frequency( lower on-time) Could I use this transformer (theoretically)

The best way to figure this out is to think of a simple (non-isolated) buck or boost converter. A forward converter is a buck with an added transformer. A flyback puts a second winding on the inductor that's already there in your boost converter.

"Can't" is too strong: there's still some magnetizing inductance that can be used in this way, up to whatever the saturation current is.  The hard part is, the power level at that point will be much lower than the nominal rating in forward mode, and saturation current isn't specified, so you can't really design with it. "Can't [operate up to nameplate forward rating]" I would definitely agree with however.
